# Why does the MD5 checksums vary after removing security from the same secure PDF?

Tags: pdf, md5

I created a simple PDF with security and then created a copy of it. After removing security from the files, I end up with different MD5 checksums for the unsecured files. Could someone explain to me why that is and if possible, how to end up with the same MD5 checksum after removing security?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really ask for a md5 checksum or do you ask for the file identifier?

Comment: *"how to end up with the same MD5 checksum after removing security?"* - Check sums are meant to be different for different data. You change the data in the pdf file by removing security. Thus, you usually change the check sum.

Comment: Inside the PDF there is a file identifier inside the footer. This one should stay the same, even if you remove encryption. You could use this one to track PDFs of same source.

Comment: PatrickF thank you for leading me in the right direction. After reading about the file identifier, I learned that it creates a unique id based on the date resulting in a different checksum even when the contents are the same.

Answer (score 0):

'Security' on a PDF file involves encrypting all the content streams. Additionally an extra set of data consisting of the keys and security type is present.

So given that there is extra data, and the binary content of the file is different, in a protected PDF file, it should be no surprise that the MD5 hash of that file is different to one which has no security applied.

Comment: And it's not a surprise. I understand that the checksums would be different between a pdf with security on and the same pdf with security removed. "After removing security from the files, I end up with different MD5 checksums for the unsecured files". I would expect the checksums for the unsecured files, which both originated from the secure file to be the same as each other, not that of the secured file.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't obvious to me. There could be many reasons, but the most likely is different white space after the file has been decrypted and rewritten. In particular CR or CR/LF at the end of the stream keywords. I'd think a binary diff of the two files would show this up.

Comment: I learned that when a PDF is created it basically creates a timestamp within the file itself. Resulting in a different checksum.

Comment: Ah yes, if the decrypting code changes the metadata that would do it too. Probably its the modification date that changed.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-are-pdf-files-different-even-if-content-same

Basically it's creating a timestamp within the PDF giving it a different checksum.

> Two files, created on a different moment, should have a different ID. The file identifier is usually a hash created based on the date, a path name, the size of the file, part of the content of the PDF file (e.g. the entries in the information dictionary).